# New issue with estpost tabulate

Tags: latex, stata

I use estpost tabulate to export several results to Latex from Stata.

I think my system admin installed a new version of something and now this function no longer works.

Try this code from the estout webpage:

```
sysuse auto, clear
//(1978 Automobile Data)

estpost tabulate rep78 foreign
esttab, cell(colpct(fmt(2))) unstack noobs
```

And I get this error: `(tabulating estimates stored by eststo; specify "." to tabulate the active results)` Part of the crazy thing is that the code still writes a blank table to my latex file, which means that the error only becomes obvious when I compile my full document

EDIT: The answer here does show that the simple solution is to include `esttab ., cell(colpct(fmt(2))) unstack noobs`. But this doesn't really solve my problem, since I have to find every instance of using this code in about 40 do files I am working with right now and using esttab.

Is there any other way around this? Could I reinstall an earlier version of esttab? Specify that I always want to tabulate the active results in a preamble somewhere?

Comment: What is the best way to contact the author of the documentation to get it changed? The documentation for estout examples is no longer correct, given this new change.

Comment: `ssc desc estout` and inspection of the help files does give you Ben Jann's email address.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
esttab ., cell(colpct(fmt(2))) unstack noobs
```

note the `.`

if you want to name your stored output, simply use:

```
estpost tabulate rep78 foreign
#store the output
eststo my_output

esttab my_output, cell(colpct(fmt(2))) unstack noobs
```

Comment: Okay, yes, that syntax does work. For my exporting needs, I can use: `esttab . using XYZ, cell(colpct(fmt(2))) unstack noobs`. I guess I am still hoping that I can get an answer where I can avoid doing this throughout my code or at least understand why this change was made in this new version of esttab.

Comment: And I apologize that I didn't come up with that... I tried a few iterations in the more complicated version of my code that this is a simple version of - must have had a typo.

Comment: This doesn't really solve my problem. Could I reinstall an earlier version of esttab? Specify that I always want to tabulate the active results in a preamble somewhere?

Comment: Part of the crazy thing is that the code still writes a blank table to my latex file, which means that the error only becomes obvious when I compile  my full document.